# Can't make variables into decimals

Tags: python, variables, decimal, python-3.5

What is going on here? I can't seem to make variables into decimals?

```
from decimal import Decimal

def calculate_lay_liability(stake, decimal_odds):
    liability = (Decimal(decimal_odds) - 1) * Decimal(stake)
    return liability

stake = 5
decimal_odds = Decimal(2.11)

print(calculate_lay_liability(stake, decimal_odds))
print(Decimal(stake) * Decimal(decimal_odds))
```

I may be using the wrong thing! I need stake * decimal_odds to equal 10.55

Comment: This code outputs `5.549999999999999378275106210` and 
`10.54999999999999937827510621`  That looks like decimal to me.

Comment: I see a lot of `Decimal` objects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the expression `Decimal(2.11)`.  There is no such number as 2.11 - at least not as an ordinary floating-point number, which is what the parameter here is: the closest value that can accurately be represented as a float is actually something like 2.109999999999999875655.  The Decimal class then *exactly* represents that inexact value.  If you want an exact Decimal, you have to construct it with an exact value: `Decimal("2.11")` does the conversion itself, without ever going through a floating-point format, so no inaccuracy is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I would not use a Decimal object but just use a float:

```
def calculate_lay_liability(stake, odds):
    liability = (odds - 1) * stake
    return liability

stake = 5
odds = 2.11

print (calculate_lay_liability(stake, odds))
print stake * odds
```

For more information on the Decimal see https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

When using a float as input to construct the Decimal value you are providing  a value that is not exact to begin with. A way around this would be to provide a string value as input and convert that directly to a Decimal.

> Decimal instances can be constructed from integers, strings, floats,
>   or tuples. Construction from an integer or a float performs an exact
>   conversion of the value of that integer or float.

This means when providing a float you will have the exact, very precise and slightly inaccurate value of your float as the decimal value. If you are already dealing with a float as input then you might want to round the value down by quantisizing:

```
decimal_odds = Decimal(2.11).quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
```

Comment: I thought it was automatically float? I realise python is using a binary calculation here, which is why the answer comes out wrong?

Comment: This is not an answer to his question, it is a suggestion whether or not a float would be a better choice.

Comment: That's great, but it's the same as what I had previously that lead me to try Decimal. Is there a way to arrive at the correct numerical answer of exactly 5.55 without rounding up?

Comment: Not with a float as input since that is not the exact answer of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
decimal_odds = Decimal("2.11")
```

... this lets Decimal start with an **exact** value instead of a float approximation. Then the final result is `Decimal('5.55')`.

On the other hand, just using float values is only off by 1.9 * 10<sup>-14</sup> % - a bet would have to be literally half a trillion dollars before the payout is off by a cent.